# Extracting a .tar.gz I get a file without extension

Tags: linux, tar

The file is this:

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpuminer/files/pooler-cpuminer-2.3.2-linux-x86.tar.gz
```

As usual I do

```
tar -xvzf pooler-cpuminer-2.3.2-linux-x86.tar.gz
```

but I just get a file called minerd without extension.
Do I have to do something with that file or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

minerd is the program you downloaded.  Run it.

`./minerd`

Comment: Oh wow I feel so stupid now, I was expecting something like .sh or something to compile. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TadaBanri  On most UNIXish systems there's a tool called [file](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file) which can help you see what type the file is. For most executables, it will call it an ELF executable, whatever the bitsize is.